# React Router DOM: Custom Route component not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

My application in total has 5 routes, out of these 5 for four of them I need a condition to be true first to let user access those routes. So I wanted to create checks for said routes.
I made PublicRoute and PrivateRoute Components

```
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';


const PublicRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => <Component {...props} />} />
);  

export default PublicRoute
```

```
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) =>
      isAuthenticated ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/" />
      )
    }
  />
);

export default PrivateRoute
```

And my app.js

```
import { Routes } from "react-router-dom"
import PublicRoute from "./components/PublicRoute"

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>

        <PublicRoute
          exact
          path="/"
          component={Com}
        />

      </Routes>
    </>
  )
}

export default App

const Com=()=>(
  <>
  <h1>Hi</h1>
  </>
)
```

And currently I am getting this error

```
 not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>
    at invariant (history.ts:48
```

Given I am returning a Route Component I can't quite understand why this error pops up. Eventually I want a way to perform checks and keep code clean, If there's another efficient way please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Routes component needs a literal Route component as the child.

This worked for me -

PublicRoute

```
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

const PublicRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Component {...rest} />
);

export default PublicRoute;
```

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import PublicRoute from "./PublicRoute";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          element={
            <PublicRoute component={Com} msg={"there"} person={"sandy"} />
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;

const Com = ({ msg, person }) => (
  <>
    <h1>
      Hi {msg} {person}
    </h1>
  </>
);
```